# How to I extract a column from a 2D array in Google Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, extract

I am new to GAS. I have built a 3D array and I would like to extract the nth column as a vector. 
In this example, the 2D array is called "skillsarray" :

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RV Partners");
var wsInfosPartners = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Infos Partners");
var skillsarray = wsInfosPartners.getRange(1, 1, 1, wsInfosPartners.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

Then when entering a value in a cell of my sheet, I'd like to check if this value is part of my 1st row in the array. If yes, I'd like to store the correponding column in a new vector :

```
function onEdit (event) {
  var celluleactive = event.range;
  var valeur = celluleactive.getValue();
  var ligne = celluleactive.getRow();
  var colonne = celluleactive.getColumn();
  var nomws = celluleactive.getSheet().getName();

  var n = skillsvector.indexOf(valeur);
```

so here in "n" I should have the row number in my array corresponding to the value I manually entered on "event". What would be the syntax to define a new array as the nth colum of my iniial array ?

Let me know if I am unclear, 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> 1. to check if this value is part of my 1st row

You need to define `skillsvector` as:

```
var skillsvector = skillsarray[0];
```

to access the first row of your array

> 2. to define a new array as the nth column of my initial array

- `n` returns you the position of the column in your row array
- to create a new array containing only cell values of the column `n`, you have to reduce the 2D value range array with the syntax [row[column]], to a vertical 1D one
- **One of several ways to do so is [mapping](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)**

Sample:

```
  var newArray = values.map(function(column){ 
    return column[n];
});
```

- **Another possibility is using a loop**

Sample:

```
var newArray = [] ;
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(values[i][n]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much ziganotschka for your help! Let me post my full code if anyone happens to encounter the same difficulties :

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var wsInfos = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
var skillsarray = wsInfosPartners.getRange(1, 1, wsInfos.getLastRow(), wsInfos.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var skillsvector = skillsarray[0];
var nbofskills = skillsvector.length;



function onEdit (e) {
  var ActiveCell = e.range;
  var val = ActiveCell.getValue();
  var row = ActiveCell.getRow();
  var col = ActiveCell.getColumn();
  var wsname = ActiveCell.getSheet().getName();
  var n = skillsvector.indexOf(val);
  var skillslist = skillsarray.map(function(column){
    return column[n];
  });

  if (wsname == "Sheet1" && col === 2 && row > 1) 
  {
  var listcell = ws.getRange(row, 3); 
  ShowSkillsList(skillslist,listcell);   
   } 

}

function ShowSkillsList(skillslist, cell){


  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(skillslist)
  .setAllowInvalid(true)
  .build();

cell.setDataValidation(rule);

}
```